# socket unstable in R

Tags: r, sockets

I am trying to let two R programs communicate by socket.
here is the code:

program A

```
con <- tryCatch(socketConnection(port=10170),error=function(e) return(FALSE))
repeat
{
  x <- tryCatch(unserialize(con),error=function(e) return(NULL))
  if(!is.null(x))
  {
    print(x)
    break
  }
  Sys.sleep(.01)
}
```

program B

```
con <- tryCatch(socketConnection(port=10170,server=T),error=function(e) return(FALSE))
Sys.sleep(3)
serialize("account and trader disconnected",con)
close(con)
```

Here is the problem. it seems that there is certain probability that program A may read the socket when program B is writing it, so A just get a part of the string. The result ends up like this:

> accou\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff

Anyone have ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know `R` but in socket programming when there are race conditions you should lock data you want to be modified by one process.

Comment: I think you mean lock data in multi-threads programming. yes,the idea is same,i need to lock the socket when writing. i just wondering if it can be done in R

Comment: You can't lock socket, you can lock objects you are modifying. As far as I know R is single-threaded so it might be a little head-ache to implement locking. Google is your friend in this situation. ;) Good luck.

Comment: I don't need to lock data,the problem now is the communication between two programs can be corrupted. i find some looking-serious socket function in Rgtk2, maybe it will help..

Comment: Maybe have separate buffer per client and exchange them. Just an idea.

Comment: have you tried the websockets package http://illposed.net/jsm2012.pdf